# Finding which matrix row has the highest column sum

Tags: r, matrix

If I have multiple matrices like

```
mymat <- matrix(c(1,2,3,8,6,1,1,3,1) , nrow=3, ncol=3)
matrix_list <- replicate(2, mymat)
column_sums <- colSums(matrix_list)
```

This shows me that row two has the highest sum, but how would I create a code that tells me that row two has the highest sum in both matrices?  So it will just show me a vector of `2,2`.  I tried this

```
for(i in 1:2) {
S <- max(matrix_list[i, ])
}
```

However this is not  doing the job.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `apply(column_sums, 2, which.max)`?

Comment: Beware that you do not have a list of matrices in `matrix_list`, you have a 3x3x2 array.  Perhaps you meant to use `simplify  = FALSE` in `replicate()`.

Comment: This works very well, you can make your comment another answer if you like.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
apply(column_sums, 2, which.max)
#[1] 2 2
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `max.col`

```
max.col(t(column_sums), "first")
#[1] 2 2
```

Comment: This works great.  What is the significance of the `t(column_sums)`?

Comment: @Killian `max.col` returns the index of the maximum value for each row.  So, by transposing it, we are getting that index.    You can check the output of 'column_sums' which is a 2 column matrix.  If  we use this without transpose, it returns 3 values for each row of the matrix.